# How to access a PC with these conditions

Tags: windows-7, networking, domain

I can't access a PC remotely and I'm trying to figure this out.

- The PC is on our corporate domain (Still in AD - Shows on PC)
- Ping via IP, not with PCName.domain
- Can't access it thru UNC Path (\IPaddress\c$ doesn't work either)
- The user logged on is a local account (\PCName\Username)
- I know the credentials for local account -- Didn't work
- My domain account is part of the local admins group

If anyone know how I can connect with UNC Path, that would be great :)

Comment: Have you confirmed with someone that the machine is actually running?

Comment: Yes, as I said, the machine is pinging on IPA but not with the computer name.

Comment: That isn't a guarantee that the machine is in a responsive state. The network's transport layer may be responding, but the application layer may not.

Comment: Good point. I just called the user and yes, the PC is up and running.

Comment: Are you able to connect using RDP to the machine? Ask the end user to enable Remote Access for this. I suspect the firewall isn't allowing connections and / or file sharing isn't set up correctly. There are hacky ways to get around this using `psexec -s` if you're the domain admin, but it's easier to walk the user through, or at least get in using RDP to do it yourself.